# How to store values from different objects in one table

Tags: grails, grails-orm

in my code I have class 'Book' with some string fields and 'BookKey' field which has some static methods and only one field with String 'key' value. My question is how to store only this 'key' value (not relation by BookKey ID), value in 'Book' table?

I don't want to create table "BookKey" in my database. I want only table 'Book' with columns: 'Key','Title' and 'Description' where 'Key' is String value of BookKey object. 
I know I have to use static transients=['key'] if I don't want to create table, but I don't know how to store values from different objects in one table.

```
class BookKey{
    public final String key;

    public BookKey(){
        this.key="key-undefined"
    }

    public BookKey(String key){
        this.key=key;
    }

    static BookKey generate(){
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String key="book-"+uuid;
        return new BookKey(key)
    }

    static BookKey from(String key){
        return new BookKey(key)
    }
}

public class Book {
    BookKey key=BookKey.generate();
    String title;
    String description;

    static transients = ['key']

    static mapping = {
        key column: 'bKey'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `static embedded` is ok, but in my situation it was better to define my own `"user-type"`and adding it to GORM mapping.

I have only one `String` field with random generated business key in my class, so I wanted to store this value as varchar in db. The solutions is:

In `Config.groovy` define:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping={
  "user-type" (type: my.package.persistence.PersistentBookKey, class: BookKey)
}
```

Create class `PersistentBookKey` which implements `UserType` interface and ovveride some methods:

```
final class PersistentBookKey implements UserType
{
    @Override
    protected BookKey createKeyFromString(String key) {
        BookKey.from(key)
    }

    @Override
    Class returnedClass() {
        BookKey
    }

    private static int [] SQL_TYPES=[Types.VARCHAR] as int[]

    @Override
    int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES
    }

    @Override
    boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode()
    }

    @Override
    Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        def key=rs.getString(names[0])
        return this.createKeyFromString(key);
    }

    @Override
    void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        BookKey persistent=value as BookKey
        st.setString(index,persistent?.getKey())
    }

    @Override
    Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value
    }

    @Override
    boolean isMutable() {
        return false  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value as Serializable
    }

    @Override
    Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached
    }

    @Override
    Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original
    }


}
```

Now BookKey objects are stored in database as Varchar, but when I get them, they are converted back to BookKey object.

For more informations you can look here:

http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/Usage.html

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Working-example-of-user-type-td1377468.html

Answer (score 2):

Put your BookKey class in `src/groovy` and configure your domain class to use [embedded](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/embedded.html). Example from the docs:

```
class Person {
    String name
    Country bornInCountry
    Country livesInCountry

    static embedded = ['bornInCountry', 'livesInCountry']
}

// If you don't want an associated table created for this class, either
// define it in the same file as Person or put Country.groovy under the
// src/groovy directory.
class Country {
    String iso3
    String name
}
```

Comment: It works, but only when I use "String key" in BookKey class. When I use "final String key" I get an error during run-app: `Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property key in class domain.model.keys.BookKey`

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the `embedded` property of Grails domain classes:

```
 static embedded = ['key']
```

See [Composition in GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#5.2.2%20Composition%20in%20GORM) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with same task. I have got an idea from DroolsGormPlugin impl. The idea is to use unique **BusinessKey**. ex. Book with id=123 has '**book@123**' BusinessKey && Author with id='q23s' has '**author@q23s**' BusinessKey. Then these BusinessKeys you can use anywhere. ex:

```
class LogDomain{
  String businessKey
  ...
}
```

you needn't has key Tables for each Damains.
Another approach is used in Spring Security to determine ACL.